Unhandled exception at 0x0056FC80 in Assignment7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0056FC80
Unhandled exception at 0x0056FC80 in Assignment7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0056FC80.
When I click build, it is successful but I keep getting this when im debugging! I need this fixed before 11:59 pm CST today!
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO :DWORD
WriteConsoleA PROTO :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD

.data
    numbers DWORD 12345678h, 23456781h, 45678123h, 78654321h, 56781234h
    buffer BYTE 9 DUP(0)

.code
main PROC
    ; Iterate through each packed decimal integer
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF numbers
    mov esi, OFFSET numbers
    mov edi, OFFSET buffer
    
convert_loop:
    ; Pass the current packed decimal integer and buffer address to PackedToAsc
    push edi
    push [esi]
    call PackedToAsc
    add esp, 8 ; Clean up the stack
    
    ; Display the ASCII string
    push OFFSET buffer
    call WriteString
    add esp, 4
    
    ; Move to the next packed decimal integer
    add esi, 4 ; Move to the next DWORD in the array
    
    ; Output a newline character
    mov edx, OFFSET CRLF
    call WriteString
    
    ; Check if all integers have been converted
    loop convert_loop

    ; Exit the program
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

PackedToAsc PROC
    ; Input: eax = packed decimal integer
    ;        edi = address of buffer to store ASCII digits
    ; Output: ASCII representation of the packed decimal integer in the buffer
    
    ; Initialize index and clear buffer
    xor ecx, ecx
    
    ; Loop through each nibble of the packed decimal integer
    mov edx, eax  ; Copy packed decimal integer
    shr edx, 28   ; Shift to get the high nibble
    and edx, 0Fh  ; Mask to isolate the nibble
    add dl, '0'   ; Convert to ASCII
    mov [edi + ecx], dl  ; Store in buffer
    inc ecx
    
    mov edx, eax  ; Copy packed decimal integer
    shr edx, 24   ; Shift to get the second nibble
    and edx, 0Fh  ; Mask to isolate the nibble
    add dl, '0'   ; Convert to ASCII
    mov [edi + ecx], dl  ; Store in buffer
    inc ecx
    
    mov edx, eax  ; Copy packed decimal integer
    shr edx, 20   ; Shift to get the third nibble
    and edx, 0Fh  ; Mask to isolate the nibble
    add dl, '0'   ; Convert to ASCII
    mov [edi + ecx], dl  ; Store in buffer
    inc ecx
    
    mov edx, eax  ; Copy packed decimal integer
    shr edx, 16   ; Shift to get the fourth nibble
    and edx, 0Fh  ; Mask to isolate the nibble
    add dl, '0'   ; Convert to ASCII
    mov [edi + ecx], dl  ; Store in buffer
    inc ecx
    
    ; Null-terminate the string
    mov byte ptr [edi + ecx], 0
    
    ret
PackedToAsc ENDP

WriteString PROC
    ; Input: esi = address of null-terminated string
    ; Output: string is displayed on console

    ; Load arguments for WriteConsoleA
    push -11           ; hConsoleOutput
    push esi           ; lpBuffer
    push 0FFFFFFFFh    ; nNumberOfCharsToWrite (-1 for null-terminated string)
    push 0             ; lpNumberOfCharsWritten
    call WriteConsoleA ; Call WriteConsoleA to display the string
    add esp, 16        ; Clean up the stack

    ret
WriteString ENDP

CRLF BYTE 0DH, 0AH, 0 ; Newline character sequence

main ENDP
END main

